# Single line for-loop to build a dictionary?

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I'm constructing a dictionary (which I'll later make into a JSON string). I construct it like this:

```
data = {}
for smallItem in bigList:
    data[smallItem] = smallItem
```

How can I make that for loop one line?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays):

```
data = {smallItem:smallItem for smallItem in bigList}
```

You might also use [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
data = dict((smallItem, smallItem) for smallItem in bigList)
```

But the dict comprehension will be faster.

As for converting this into a JSON string, you can use [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps).

Comment: The only advantage of `dict` with a generator expression is that it works with Python2.6 and below which may be important

Comment: Thanks, I'm a newbie to python, and I've been trying to find the name to this feature.

Comment: Good answer. thanks. Just wondering - if i want to apply this for multiple fields, what should be the syntax?

Comment: IT does not work if we have two items in dict. How to create one if there are more than one items?

Answer (score 8):

Actually in this specific case you don't even need a dictionary comprehension since you are using duplicate key/value pairs

```
>>> bigList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> dict(zip(bigList, bigList))
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5}
```

Comment: This actually led me to learn a new method `zip` +1

Comment: Is this faster than the top answer?

Comment: @Alexander I did some rough timings on a small and big version of `bigList` (not super scientific) and from my tests dictionary comprehension is faster in both cases.