# How can you find what percentage of a Numpy Array has some value X?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, percentage

Say I have a numpy array:

```
array = np.array(['Fe', 'Pt', 'Ce', 'Nd', 'Pt', 'Fe', ..., 'Pt', 'Ce', 'Fe', 'Fe'])
```

Where each entry in the array is either 'Fe', 'Pt', 'Ce', or 'Nd'. I understand how to get the percentage for a single entry, something like:

```
percentage = np.sum(array = 'Fe')/array.shape[0]*100
```

But what if I want to get the percentage for every unique string value? Is there a way to vectorize that operation and generalise it to an arbitrary number of unique string values?

Ideally I would like something like:

```
percentages = np.some_operation(array)
```

Which produces output like:

```
percentages = {'Fe': 25, 'Pt': 15, 'Nd': 45, 'Ce': 15}
```

It doesn't have to be in the form of a dictionary, so long as it's clear which percentage belongs to which element. The arrays I intend to work on could be anywhere from 1,000 to 1,000,000 entries long.

Comment: if this were `pandas` you could use `value_counts`. Maybe, you are better off just use a `collecitons.Counter`... why is this data in a numpy array to begin with? How large will it be?

Comment: Please see clarification on length added to the bottom of the question. The data is stored in a numpy array as part of structured array, which contains an element designation as a string, and a coordinate vector stored as a numpy array. Having the two together in a single structured array improved performance, and simplifies my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use the `return_counts` argument from `np.unique` :

```
uniques, counts = np.unique(array, return_counts=True)
```

And then create a dictionnary from your 2 arrays :

```
percentages = dict(zip(uniques, counts * 100 / len(array)))
```

Comment: ah, forgot `np.unique` returns counts. Very good way to do this.

Comment: I just found this answer myself! Pipped at the post, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I googled a bit and found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27715703/15503170
You can do it like this :

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array(['Fe', 'Pt', 'Ce', 'Nd', 'Pt', 'Fe', 'Pt', 'Ce', 'Fe', 'Fe'])
percentage = {i:np.sum(array == i)/array.shape[0]*100 for i in array}

print(percentage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to `np.unique`, you can use `collections.Counter`

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

arr = np.array(['Fe', 'Pt', 'Ce', 'Nd', 'Pt', 'Fe', 'Pt', 'Ce', 'Fe', 'Fe'])
ln = arr.shape[0]

cnt = Counter(arr)
ans = {i: cnt[i]*100/ln for i in cnt}

print(ans)
```

Output:

```
{'Fe': 36.36363636363637, 'Pt': 27.272727272727273, 'Ce': 18.181818181818183, 'Nd': 9.090909090909092}
```